# jQuery table rows won't render in within table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am using jQuery to add and remove table rows for a collection of forms within another form in Symfony 4. This was not easy, but eventually made it work. With a macro in Twig I can get this rendered result:

```
<table>
  <div id="document-list" data-prototype="
    <tr>
        <td>
           <fieldset class=&quot;form-group&quot;>
             <div id=&quot;program_programDocument___name__&quot; novalidate=&quot;novalidate&quot;>
                <div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;program_programDocument___name___name&quot; name=&quot;program[programDocument][__name__][name]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot;/>
                </div>
             </div>
          </fieldset>
       </td>
       <td>
          <button type=&quot;button&quot;class=&quot;remove-collection-widget&quot;data-list=&quot;#remove-collection-widget&quot;>Remove</button>
       </td>
    </tr>" data-widget-tags="<div></div>">
  </div>
</table>
<button type="button" class="add-another-collection-widget" data-list="#document-list">Add document</button>
```

I cleaned up this code as much as possible to make it readable. All the HTML within `data-prototype="...."` is how it should be. My code works (ish) together with some jQuery:

```
jQuery('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function(e) {
  var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('data-list'));
  // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
  var counter = list.data('widget-counter') | list.children().length;
  // grab the prototype template
  var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
  // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
  // with a number that's unique to your emails
  // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
  newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
  // Increase the counter
  counter++;
  // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
  list.data('widget-counter', counter);

  // create a new list element and add it to the list
  var newElem = jQuery(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
  newElem.appendTo(list);
});
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".remove-collection-widget", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

The problem is, the rendered result when added more form rows is that they don't actually end up within the table. You can see for yourself ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kzvq7dw/)) the result looks alright, but in reality it's not.

I am pretty sure it has to do with my jQuery, but I am stuck now and hope some of you can point out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a `div` as a direct child of a `table` isn't proper HTML, which is what's tripping it up.

- Move `id="document-list" data-prototype="...` to `table` element
- Get rid of `div` inside `table`
- Change `data-widget-tags` to `tr` instead of `div`
- Remove wrapping `tr` from `data-prototype`

#### Solution

```js
jQuery('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function(e) {
  var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('data-list'));
  var counter = list.data('widget-counter') | list.children().length;
  var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
  newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
  counter++;
  list.data('widget-counter', counter);
  var newElem = jQuery(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
  newElem.appendTo(list);
});

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".remove-collection-widget", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="document-list" data-prototype="
        <td>
           <fieldset class=&quot;form-group&quot;>
             <div id=&quot;program_programDocument___name__&quot; novalidate=&quot;novalidate&quot;>
                <div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;program_programDocument___name___name&quot; name=&quot;program[programDocument][__name__][name]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot;/>
                </div>
             </div>
          </fieldset>
       </td>
       <td>
          <button type=&quot;button&quot;class=&quot;remove-collection-widget&quot;data-list=&quot;#remove-collection-widget&quot;>Remove</button>
       </td>" data-widget-tags="<tr></tr>">
</table>
<button type="button" class="add-another-collection-widget" data-list="#document-list">Add document</button>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table (see Permitted Content)

Comment: For some reason I kept on messing with the jQuery all the time I did not even see how the html was wrong. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It's the browser trying to outsmart you by guessing what it thinks you're trying to do by following the W3C spec.